# Activator.CreateInstance with dynamic objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

there are many questions arround about this theme, but I didn't find one, which answers my question:

I'm toying arround with the MVVM. In order to give the views a possibility to request a ViewModel-switch, I implemented a Event in the abstract base class.
My method to switch looking like this:

```
    private void ChangeCurrentView(Type viewType, IEnumerable<Object> constructorArguments)
    {
        if (_currentContent != null)
        { 
            _currentContent.ChangeViewRequested -= view_ChangeViewRequested;
        }

        ViewModelBase vm;
        if (constructorArguments == null)
        { 
            vm = (ViewModelBase)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
        }
        else
        {
            vm = (ViewModelBase)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType, constructorArguments);
        }
        vm.ChangeViewRequested += view_ChangeViewRequested;
        _currentContent = vm;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentContent");
    }
```

My problem lies in the CreateInstance: As you can see I have to check if the arguments are null and if so, I use the method without arguments. But even if the arguments are filled, for example:

```
public QuestionViewModel(Question question)
```

and the constructorArgument has just 1 object of this type, it doesn't seem to handle this proper.

is there a possibility to get this dynamic creating work, or are there other ways to make this anyhow happen?

Thanks as usual and a good start in the week.

Matthias

Edit: The error I get is "The constructor for the type "MMU.QuestionHelper.GUI.ViewModel.QuestionViewModel" was not found."

I translated it myself, because my VS is in german.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _it doesn't seem to handle this proper_?

Comment: Added the error messagr, sec

Comment: I think you may pass an invalid number of arguments to the constructor so .net cannot find the right one. It takes one argument. How many of them do you have in your `constructorArguments`? Maybe you need to change the constructor's signature.

Comment: Delete all that and use DataTemplates. Also, a view shouldn't dictate what ViewModel is under it. the ViewModel is conceptually part of the application's logic and if anything, the ViewModel should determine to "switch itself to something else" because the application logic dictates what should happen, and not the UI. With this approach DataTemplates are much more suitable.

Comment: HighCore do you have a example how to do this? Especially switch itself to something else? P.S.: Yeah I have exatly one object in the list, which is a Question, so should this work?